# Field isn't spanning the full table row

Tags: visualforce, html

I have css applied to a table. I want to make a row span the entire table that says information, highlighted a color, and centered.  Instead it's just saying "information" and not centered across the row

```
<apex:component access="global" controller="PPACABenefitChecklistEmailTemplateHelper"> 
    <apex:attribute id="oppId" assignTo="{!oppId}" name="opportunityIDFromEmail" type="String" description="The Opporunity's SF ID"/>    
    <br/>
    <apex:repeat var="c" value="{!Checklists}">
            <table class="maintable">
                 <td class="section">

 <!--------LINE BELOW NOT WORKING----->
                    <table>    <tr BGCOLOR="#2d97cc">  <td  ALIGN="center" COLSPAN="2">Information</td></tr> </table>
<!---------WORKS FINE---------->
                    <table class="sub_section"> <tr>  <td class="mysub_section_label">Number:</td> <td class="sub_section_data"> {!c.name}</td></tr></table>
                    <table class="sub_section"> <tr>  <td class="mysub_section_label">Opportunity:</td>     <td class="sub_section_data"> {!c.Opportunity__r.name}</td> </tr></table>
                </td>  
          </table>     
<br/><br/><br/><br/>                 


     </apex:repeat>  



</apex:component>
```

CSS from email template

```
    <messaging:attachment renderAs="PDF" filename="OpporunityChecklists-{!LEFT(relatedTo.id,15)}">


    <style>

    body,table,td,p,h1
    { font-family:"Lucida Grande", verdana, helvetica, arial, sans-serif; }

    body,table,td,p
    { font-size: 11px; }

    h1
    { font-size:14px; font-weight: bold; padding-bottom:1px; }

    table.toptable { outline: 0px solid #2d97cc; border: 0px solid #2d97cc; cellpadding: 2px; font-size:14px; width: 620px;}
    table.maintable { outline: 1px solid #2d97cc; border: 1px solid #2d97cc; cellpadding: -2px; border-collapse:collapse; width: 620px;}
    table.bottomtable { outline: 0px solid #2d97cc; border: 0px solid #2d97cc; cellpadding: 2px; font-size:14px; width: 620px;}

    td.leftsection { outline: 0px solid #2d97cc; border: 1px solid #2d97cc; border-collapse:collapse; text-align:right; font-size:14px; padding-right:10px; width: 72px; }
    td.section { outline: 0px solid #2d97cc; border: 1px solid #2d97cc; border-collapse:collapse; }

    td.banner {height: 52px; font-size: 14px; color: #f7951e; font-weight: bold; }
    td.logo {text-align:right;}
    td.header { padding-top:20px; padding-right: 10px; padding-left:10px; paqdding-bottom:0px; text-align:center; }
    td.headernote { padding-top:0px; padding-right: 20px; padding-left:20px; text-align:center; text-valign: top; color: #0083c4; font-size: -1px;}

    .largertext
    {font-size: 14px;}

    .mysub_section_label
    {width: 250px; font-size: 10px;}

    .sub_section_data
    {font-weight: bold;font-size: 10 px;  }

    .message
    {font-style: italic; font-size: 9px;}

    .footer_link
    { padding-top:20px; text-align:center; color: #f7951e; font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; width: 740px;}


    </style>

     <html>
            <head/>
            <body>
    <c:EmailTemplateHelper opportunityIDFromEmail="{!relatedTo.id}" />
      </body>
        </html>
    </messaging:attachment>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables, by default, have only enough width to accommodate their contents. I would hazard a guess that the other two tables work because of the `class="sub_section"` attribute on the table. You don't need to use that particular style-- you could just add `width="100%"`, which will expand the table to the right boundary of the enclosing element.